# Timex.to_naive_datetime subtracts an hour

Tags: datetime, elixir

Calling `Timex.to_naive_datetime` to convert to a naive datetime without the timezone subtracts an hour from the input datetime

I have tried other timezones and ruled out the possibility of daylight saving time conversion.

```elixir
d = %DateTime{
  year: 2000,
  month: 2,
  day: 29,
  zone_abbr: "CET",
  hour: 23,
  minute: 0,
  second: 7,
  microsecond: {0, 0},
  utc_offset: 3600,
  std_offset: 0,
  time_zone: "Europe/Warsaw"
}
#=> # DateTime<2000-02-29 23:00:07+01:00 CET Europe/Warsaw>

Timex.to_naive_datetime(d)
#=> ~N[2000-02-29 22:00:07]

d2 = %DateTime{
  year: 2019,
  month: 3,
  day: 2,
  zone_abbr: "PST",
  hour: 23,
  minute: 0,
  second: 7,
  microsecond: {0, 0},
  utc_offset: 3600,
  std_offset: 0,
  time_zone: "America/Los_Angeles"
}
#=> #DateTime<2019-03-02 23:00:07+01:00 PST America/Los_Angeles>

Timex.to_naive_datetime(d2)
#=> ~N[2019-03-02 22:00:07]
```

I am expecting the first datetime to be converted to `~N[2000-02-29 23:00:07]`, but the output is `~N[2000-02-29 22:00:07]`.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the structs you create contain `utc_offset: 3600`, which is UTC+1.

```elixir
#DateTime<2000-02-29 23:00:07+01:00 CET Europe/Warsaw>
#DateTime<2019-03-02 23:00:07+01:00 PST America/Los_Angeles>
```

How did the `+01:00` that get there for `America/Los_Angeles`? It's not valid for that timezone. If I generate the date using one of the standard functions:

```elixir
d3 = Timex.to_datetime({{2019,3, 2}, {23, 0, 7}}, "America/Los_Angeles")
#=> #DateTime<2019-03-02 23:00:07-08:00 PST America/Los_Angeles>
Timex.to_naive_datetime(d3)
#=> ~N[2019-03-03 07:00:07]
```

I get the correct timezone offset. It seems [`Timex.to_naive_datetime/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#to_naive_datetime/1) returns the UTC value of the timezone. If you just want to drop the timezone information, you can use [`DateTime.to_naive/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#to_naive/1):

```elixir
d1
#=> #DateTime<2000-02-29 23:00:07+01:00 CET Europe/Warsaw>
DateTime.to_naive(d1)
#=> ~N[2000-02-29 23:00:07]
```

Comment: This. It’s 2019 and `DateTime` is robust enough to avoid using `Timex` in general. It was great in `v1.0` era, but now there is nothing one cannot do with plain `DateTime`.

Comment: If it answered your question, please click the check mark on the left, thanks.